# How to access custom meta of publication in JAVA?

Tags: content-delivery, java, metadata, 2013-sp1

I have some meta data at the Publication level which I am trying to access using the Content Delivery API (JAVA), I can see the functions to get Page & Component metadata but could't find the way to get the same for Publication.

Can someone provide me any help or pointers.

Tridion Version 2013

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the Publication Metadata could be accessed using the Content Delivery API.

When we need to have publication properties like constants, we usually have a Component of a Constant Schema (of type Name/Value pairs), that can be published dynamically to be accessible in in the Presentation Side, by means of the Content Delivery API or publishing a properties file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you think OData webservice can provide me the information?

Also, I didn't understand one thing when I tried to access http://www-server.com:8083/cd_webservice/odata.svc/Publications, I got the list of all the published publications but there is no way to find the list of published publications through Content Delivery API, how as a new user you can understand which service to use or I am missing something?

Comment: The Content Delivery API is intended to access dynamic content inside a publication, so the entry point to the API is allways initializing a class with the PublicationId. OData exposes all the content in the Broker Database and has a list of publications, but when you access one of its components, always are characterized by its PublicationId also. I can't think of an scenario where the list of publications must be needed in the Presentation Side, as you are working in a Published site (a certain Publication).